# SQL Server update - is ther a way to avoid duplicates by skipping rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, constraints

I am trying to move data from one locale to another if is does not already exist in the second locale.  The statement I am using to do so, takes 20 hours to execute, so I would appreciate any ideas on how to do this more efficiently.

```
update table 
set localeid = 3 
where localeid = 1 
  and not exists 
          (select id from table as b where localeid = 3 and id = b.id)
```

I was wondering if there is some way to use a constraint and have SQL skip rows where the constraint is violated rather than fail the whole update. In this case the constraint would be to make `id,localeid` primary keys.

Can this be done?

p.s. the indexes required to optimize this query are in place, but it still takes forever due to the massive size of this database which has over 70 million entries.

Comment: Can you post the query plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminating the subquery, as suggested by Damien and Becuzz, may help...  If not, you can try the below.  EXISTS will always be faster than NOT EXISTS...  So start by getting the Ids you *want* to update rather than excluding the ones you *don't* want.  Run the below up to the index creation on the temp table.  Even with 70 million rows, it should not take too long.

```
create table #IdsToUpdate (Id INT);

insert  #IdsToUpdate (Id)
select  id 
from    table 
group by id
having  max(case when localeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;

create index in1 on #IdsToUpdate(Id);
```

Then try the actual update based on the temp table:

```
update  t
set     t.localeid = 3
from    table t
where   exists (
            select  top 1 1
            from    #IdsToUpdate i
            where   i.Id = t.id);
```

Also, if possible...  can you put your DB into simple recovery mode?  Logged updates take a lot longer.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?  This might do better as it eliminates the subquery.

```
update a
set localeid = 3
from table a
left join table b on b.id = a.id and b.localeid = 3
where a.localeid = 1
and b.id is null
```

Comment: I have not tried this yet, do you think it would be better or worse than using the temporary table above?

Comment: @AndrewLindzon Without trying it I couldn't say for sure that it would be faster or slower than the temp table solution.  It depends on how your server creates the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally write this as:

```
update a
   set localeid = 3
from
   table a
     left join
   table b
     on
        a.id = b.id and
        b.localeid = 3
where
    a.localeid = 1 and
    b.id is null
```

But whether it will improve the performance, I don't know